# Javascript <select> output

Tags: javascript, html

I gave two `<select>` controls, and the values of the second should be dynamically populated based on the selection in the first. When you select for Example `A`, the corresponding words should appear as options in the second dropwdown. How can I do it? I tried something but the list just appears horizontal and I need it vertical.

```js
var teams = [
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    " Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    " Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten"],
    
    listTeam = function listTeam(sel) {
        var val = document.getElementById('standings').value, //get the selected value
            team = teams[val], //get the selected team, based on value
            opt = document.createElement('option'), //create an <option> element
            lb = document.getElementById('leaderBoard'), //get the leaderBoard select element
            children = lb.children.length,
            child = null,
            i = 0; //incrementor
        opt.innerText = team;
        for (i = 0; i < children; i += 1) {
            
            child = lb.children[0];
            lb.removeChild(child);
        }
        lb.appendChild(opt);
    };
listTeam();
```

```html
<select id='standings' name='standings' onchange="listTeam(this)">

  <option value='0'>A</option>
  <option value='1'>B</option>
  <option value='2'>C</option>
  <option value='3'>D</option>
  <option value='4'>E</option>
</select>


<select id='leaderBoard' name='leaderBoard' multiple="multiple" size="1" style="width: 100px;"></select>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not very clear what you're asking. What's an "und"?

Comment: Sorry und (german) is and. I need select when i have for Example A,B,C,D... and the output is for "a" list with some words

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r6te77ys/ Like this?

Comment: yes almost . In this example the list is horizontal, but i need it vertikal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each value in a `<select>` element is an individual `<option>` element. Split your string of names into individual elements using the JavaScript string `split` method, and then create an `option` element for each one and put that in your list.

The relevant code is here, and the full runnable example is below.

```
var people = team.split(/\s/);
for (var j=0; j<people.length; j++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option')
    opt.innerText = people[j];
    lb.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Also, note that clearing the leaderboard is as easy as:

```
lb.options.length = 0;
```

Full example:

```js
var teams = [
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    " Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    " Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten"],
    
    listTeam = function listTeam(sel) {
        var val = document.getElementById('standings').value, //get the selected value
            team = teams[val], //get the selected team, based on value
            lb = document.getElementById('leaderBoard'); //get the leaderBoard select element

        lb.options.length = 0;

        var people = team.trim().split(/\s/);
        for (var j=0; j<people.length; j++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option')
            opt.innerText = people[j];
            lb.appendChild(opt);
        }
    };
listTeam();
```

```html
<select id='standings' name='standings' onchange="listTeam(this)">

  <option value='0'>A</option>
  <option value='1'>B</option>
  <option value='2'>C</option>
  <option value='3'>D</option>
  <option value='4'>E</option>
</select>


<select id='leaderBoard' name='leaderBoard' multiple="multiple" size="1" style="width: 100px;"></select>
```

Comment: thank you so much. Do you know how can every word like hyperlink to other page ?

Comment: @Lili No problem! Follow-up questions should be asked as a separate question (looks like you already asked a new question for that). If this, or any other answer, helped you solve your problem you should [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205949) to show that the issue was resolved, and help other folks find it in future (plus it gives a little credit to the person who answered).

Answer (score 0):

```
var teams = [
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    " Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    " Baumwolle Bettkasten",
    "Bambus Baumwolle Bettkasten"
],

listTeam = function (sel) {
    var val = sel?sel.value:0, //get the selected value
     team = teams[val],  //get the selected team, based on value
     lb = document.getElementById('leaderBoard'); //get the leaderBoard select
     lb.options.length = 0;
     optvals = team.split(" ");
    for(i=0;i<optvals.length;i++) {
        opt = document.createElement('option'); //create an <option> element
        opt.text = optvals[i];
        opt.value = i;
        lb.add(opt);
        }
};
listTeam();
```